# Working with bitmap in WPF

Tags: wpf, bitmap, pixel

Is there any sane way to work with bitmaps in WPF? I'd like similar functionality as `System.Drawing.Bitmap`: be able to load image from file and get and set the color of particular pixels.

I know about `WriteableBitmap`, but I don't want to work with `Array`s of gods-know-what (I couldn't find that on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346816.aspx)), or pointers. I just want to read or write pixel, it shouldn't be that hard!

I also know that I can [use Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap) to work with `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in WPF, but that's not nice either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding specific pixel colors of a BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176910/finding-specific-pixel-colors-of-a-bitmapimage)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's [something on how to do get pixel info from a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176910/finding-specific-pixel-colors-of-a-bitmapimage).

Although, if you'd prefer to work with a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` you might want to add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` and use it instead.

Here's a [somewhat-related forum post on image manipulation in WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/580fca03-d15b-48b2-9fb3-2e6fec8a2c68/).