# Opacity in images in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

How can I detect transparent pixels in an `image` using WPF so that I know where a user clicks?

Comment: i think most people's first question back to you is WHY do you need to detect transparent pixels?  we probably would have a better answer about what you're trying to do than HOW you're trying to do it.  What do you need to do with the transparent pixels?

Comment: WHY to detect where user click picture

Answer (score 0):

U don't need Image class, it is not design for pixel manipulation. Rater use Bitmap* class

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"/test.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi.EndInit();
```

[an exapmle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176910/finding-specific-pixel-colors-of-a-bitmapimage)

Implement public PixelColor[,] GetPixels(BitmapSource source) method and then interate through returned array to find Alpha channel ( a simple loop). Mind that some images does not support transparency and the file vary depends on structure (ARGB, RGBA) etc.

Comment: heu can you help me more - Bitmap* What class should i use? *Image not supported?