# Get The Colour Of Any Pixel In A BitmapFrame?

Tags: wpf, imaging

I want to write some tests to verify that an IValueConverter rotates an image according to it's EXIF Metadata for orientation.

I've created a test image which is 400px wide and 300px high, the top half of which is white and the lower half is black.

If I can examine the colours of the pixels in the corners of the image then I can write my tests and make assertions according to the following table:

```
Orientation                Top Left    Top Right    Bottom Left   Bottom Right
Landscape                  White       White        Black         Black
Portrait Clockwise         Black       White        Black         White
Portrait Anti Clockwise    White       Black        White         Black
```

(I am not expecting images to be upside-down or reflected either horizontally or vertically)

```
using(var f = new FileStream(@"C:\test.jpg",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
     var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(f);
}
```

How can I access the corner pixels and examine whether they are black or white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from here applies to BitmapFrame as well: [Finding specific pixel colors of a BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176910/finding-specific-pixel-colors-of-a-bitmapimage)

Copy the data into a byte array and carefully parse the array

Comment: thanks that's great, so good in fact that I've voted to close my own question ;)