# Converting b/w canvas to 2D array

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a character recognizer app and trying to convert a canvas image to a 2d array of ints. The dimensions are 250x250 and is black and white. If the pixel is black, I want it to set the array value to 1. How can I determine the pixel color for each pixel to populate my array? (I am working with WPF and C#)

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is this image an opened image from an external file or id it dynamically drawn when user is interacting with the applicetion? If it's read from a file, you can try to use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176910/finding-specific-pixel-colors-of-a-bitmapimage.