# WriteableImage - how to obtain color of pixel?

Tags: c#, wpf

Like in the title. I need to obtain each value: red, green and blue of specific pixel. What is the best way to do that? I didn't find any examples of copypixels in WriteableImage.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'm assuming that by `WriteableImage` you mean `WriteableBitmap`. Have a look at [Finding specific pixel colors of a `BitmapImage`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1740553/63011) (In particularly at `PixelColor[,] GetPixels(BitmapSource source)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use with `WriteableBitmapEx Framework`

Link : http://wp7rocks.com/marketplace/components/details/51

Comment: I downloaded it and added reference. What should i do next?