# background of a part of ContentControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to get the background of spesific area of ContentControl.

Here is my ContentControl ;

[image: CompleteContentControl]

The area I would like to have is (topright of the ContentControl) ;

[image: area]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put your content control into another content control and set the horizontal and vertical position to topright. In the following example I use an image in a grid.

```
<Grid>
        <Image
            x:Name="MyImage"
            Height="22"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Margin="10"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="22" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried now but I dont know what to do, basically I want to get the background color of the second image which is the corner. I have 2 content controls and I want to find the collusion. Please check my previous question and give me some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520077/wpf-image-collison-detection/23520230?noredirect=1#comment36077284_23520230