# WPF Colorize Grayscale BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

How do I colorize a grayscale `BitmapImage` in WPF (preferably) using the MVVM pattern?

This is the `DataTemplate` that I use in my `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}" />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Z}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

I've looked at MatrixTransform but that seems to be only used for skewing / rotating the image?

This is what I've used in Java to achieve the same:

```
public static void colorize(BufferedImage image, Color maskColor)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
            if( (pixel >> 24) == 0x00 )
                continue;

            Color color = new Color(pixel);
            float red   = (color.getRed()   / 255.0F) * (maskColor.getRed()   / 255.0F);
            float green = (color.getGreen() / 255.0F) * (maskColor.getGreen()   / 255.0F);
            float blue  = (color.getBlue()  / 255.0F) * (maskColor.getBlue()   / 255.0F);

            color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            int rgb = color.getRGB();
            image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to colorize a grayscale image? I am relatively new to WPF.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. How would a WPF Transform ever change colors of a bitmap? That makes absolutely no sense. Just as setting `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"` on a ScaleTransform.

Comment: If that is not set it is rendered as blurry edges.

Comment: And what is a "colorized grayscale image" at all? Please explain.

Comment: You need to set `BitmapScalingMode` in places such as `ImageSource`,`BitmapImage`,`ImageBrush`

Comment: Oh @clemens....you are right.....Respect ur WPF knowledge always

Comment: You'd have to translate your 255 grades of gray - or whatever you have in your bitmap into colours or a colour gradient. That wouldn't be in a transform. I suppose it could be in a  custom shader effect.

Comment: @Clemens I've added a Java example. Hopefully that will clarify what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Do the same in WPF/C# with a WriteableBitmap, or pass the pixel array to [BitmpaSource.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616045(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This thread discusses how to get the bytes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176910/finding-specific-pixel-colors-of-a-bitmapimage

Comment: @Andy I know I can colorize it in C# but I was looking for a XAML solution.

Comment: "I know I can colorize it in C#" That's good, because there is no built-in "XAML solution". You may probably use a Binding Converter, which however is also written in C#.

Comment: I think you could encapsulate the code in a custom shader but you'd still be writing code. Just in a different place and using a relatively rare technique.

Comment: @Andy Sounds like a proper solution as I felt 'preprocessing' the image is hacky as it limits reusing it (which is part of my use case, multiple colors). Any pointers for resources I can read upon to implement this?

Comment: I've never written an effect myself but you could start your research by reading this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71617/Getting-Started-with-Shader-Effects-in-WPF